# Fixed serialization field order

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need a basic sign of a form submissión. I serialize the fields and get sha1 of json string. The problem is th serializer, sort the fields randomly. Can I set a fixed fields order?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you´re speaking about front-end.

I´m talking hearsay but dictionary order attributes randomly as well. So Why don´t you order them by javascript or others? When you receive the Json, you can order the values and then paint them. Kind of (selection sort):

```
var data = json.split(";");
var i,j,k
for (var i = -1; i < data.length(); i++){
    for (j = k = i; k < data.length(); k++ ) {
      if (data[j] > data[k]) j = k;
    }
    [arr[j], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[j]];
 }
 return data;
}
```

You can use another sorting algorythm if you want. 
https://h3manth.com/javascript-sorting/

Comment: No. I generate the sha1 string, before save the form inside a django class based view in the app's views.py file-> CreateView ->  def form_valid()

Comment: Yes, I mean, for what are you using a JSON? It use to be for Web Services, Ajax,...? You have to generate the JSON in back-end for passing it to front-end. For that, if JSON is disordered you have to recover it (in front-end) and order it. Then you can paint it in your template. 
When you recover the JSON (in client) coming from server, for example with a function JS called from onload() of body, you could use those data, ordering them and then passing to the template for paint them how you want.